# GNOME Files: Where are "Networks" cached?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, nautilus

So, on this Ubuntu 18.04 box* running `Files 3.26.4` under `Other Locations` I have this entry for a long gone Brother printing station thing:
[image: Screenshot of GNOME Files 3.26.4 showing "Other Locations" with an entry under "Network" named "brcm93390smwvg2-2"]

Since it is clearly gone, there is no sensible way of interaction, so I wondered where this might be cached and how to remove it. Unfortunately, I could not find any documentation on this anywhere and searching for the raw string in `gconf-editor`, `dconf-editor` and recursively `grep`ping `.config` also did not bring up any hits.

So, the question is: Where are the entries under "Network" in GNOME Files 3.26.4 saved/cached?

(*The author is aware of the outdatedness of this OS.)

**Edit**: The printer was never installed on this machine, so this cannot be a remnant of some driver installation.

Comment: Try `lpadmin -x brcm93390smwvg2-2`.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 is EoL since April. Please upgrade to a supported release ASAP and unless you have an ESM contract you shouldn't even keep it online and/or use network dependent features.

Comment: @harrymc: ```lpadmin: The printer or class does not exist.```

Comment: @ChanganAuto: I cannot see how upgrading would solve the issue or answer the question. Do you have any pointers into that right direction as well?

Comment: Do you see it using `lpinfo -v` ?

Comment: @harrymc: No, it's not among them. I noticed that the entry vanishes when I turn off the wired connection. It comes back almost immediately after turning it back on again.

Comment: Some keywords that could help/are related: Bonjour, mDNS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not cached by GNOME; the corresponding GVfs providers all take their data "live" from external sources. There are several sources that `network:///` gets its data from – look at the internal GVfs path names to get hints:

```
gio list network:///
```

This will show the 'raw' item name, such as `dnssd-something`, and will reveal it as originating either from DNS-SD (aka Bonjour, aka mDNS, discovered via avahi-daemon) or from SMB (more accurately NetBIOS, discovered via Samba)... or perhaps from Google Cloud Print, which GNOME used to integrate with.

If the result is DNS-SD, the data was received from avahi-daemon, which has no persistent cache; any ghost entries should disappear after restarting the service. Try `avahi-browse`, or the graphical `avahi-discover`, and/or Wireshark or tcpdump to figure out what's producing the service advertisements. (Use the capture filter `port 5353`.)

Comment: There it is: ```dnssd-domain-brcm93390smwvg2-2._sftp-ssh._tcp```. Thank you :) Will try and see where this comes from and try turning it off.